# Getting the revision number of the end of a branch in WinCvs

Tags: version-control, branch, versioning, cvs, wincvs

I need a CVS command that given the name of a branch, it will give you the revision number of the last file in that branch.

---

CVS Tree structure:

```
(filename)
    |
    +--> 1.1-----(branch)
          |         |
          |      1.1.1.1
          |         |
          |      1.1.1.2
          |         |
          |      1.1.1.3
          |
          |
         1.2
          |
          |
          :
```

### For example: Using a CVS command, given the tag name "branch", how can I get CVS to give me the revision number "1.1.1.3"?

---

I have tried using the `log` command and expected to be able to parse the output of the `log` command in order to get the version number, but the version that the `log` command outputs for the branch does not match the version number at the end of the branch.

ex: `cvs -Q log -h filename`

---

CVS Version information:

[image]

---

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225099/get-revision-number-of-a-tagged-file-in-wincvs) about getting the version number of a file from a tag name.  I never got a clear answer on how to do that either, but I was able to find a workaround by parsing the `log` output with a Perl script.

Since the `log` output for the branch does not match the version number at the end of the branch my Perl script solution doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `cvs log -rMyBranch. MyFilename`, where `MyBranch.` is branch in question **with dot added as last character**, and `MyFilename` is filename in question.

Example:

`cvs log -rTestBranch. TestFile.txt`

```
RCS file: C:\cvsroot/TestRepository/TestFile.txt,v
Working file: TestFile.txt
head: 1.2
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
    TestBranch: 1.2.0.2
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 4; selected revisions: 1
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.2.2.2
date: 2015/06/08 18:32:52;  author: Codeguard;  state: Exp;  lines: +1 -1;  kopt: kv;  commitid: 117c5575dfce6e9e;  filename: TestFile.txt;
2
=============================================================================
```

From there, you can easily parse the revision.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I never noticed in the documentation that adding the "." will give you the head of the branch!